# Mathematical intuitionism, possibly

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mathematics

Mathematical intuitionism asserts as a vital principle that it's not enough to assert that something exists, it must be constructed - that is shown.

What does this mean for the truth value for a proposition such as:

> A: there are is a series of 314159 zeroes in the expansion of pi

For A, we can demand a proof that shows this; but until this is done we cannot say that A is either true or false; this is somewhat like Aristotles discussion of future contingents; for in the future, we may know, and then we can definitely assert that P is true or P is false.

Can we modify the notion of a truth value to take this into account?

That is use *modal* truth values, if there is such a thing.

ie *possibly true* and *possibly false*

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that attitude is constructivism, which, at root, is a variety of formalism.  Mathematics is mathematics only when it takes the *form* of a construction.

Surely, the easiest way to reason naively without getting tricked by the Law of the Excluded Middle into overestimating one's certainty is to stay grounded in finite constructions, but it is not the only way.  And it is, to some degree a delusion to believe everything can be shown, or that those things that cannot be show can always be captured in axioms.  Diagonalization survives in intuitionism, and Goedel's incompleteness theorem is transfinitely constructive by nature.  So if it weren't obvious, you could prove intuitionistically that this basic notion of constructivism is as weak as all other formalist positions.

Unlike in formalist takes (including constructivism), there need be no attempt at the "arithmetization of analysis".  We can accept Euclidean space from intuition and simply clarify it over time, taking the abstracted version of the geometry of our sensory apparatus as basic, rather than trying to construct it from set theory, and in the process avoiding artificial meanings for all the contents of geometry.  This is quite necessary, because a lot of the power of artificial constructions we have become accustomed to (e.g. that all Dedekind cuts are well-defined) implicitly relies upon strict negation.

But deeper ontological considerations aside, the two notions do have in common that we cannot presume the map of meaningful statements to just two truth values is total.  They react to it in different ways.

Heyting provided an underlayment for intuitionism that is not entirely constructivist, but has a strong definition of proof.  From that point of view, statements simply have another dimension to their truth value, they can be proven or unproved, but when unproven, they can also be disproven or un-disproven.  Everything is determined by this forking of the state, and you can pretty readily get used to this tristate logic.

You can also model intuitionistic deduction as the strongest modal logic where box means 'can be proven' and diamond means 'might be proven' and all axioms and preconditions can only be given as box-statements.  All constructivisms are also to some degree captured by different modal logics like this, but they have a further refinement of what is meant by 'proof' beyond what the modal operators would necessarily force down on them.

This kind of cleanliness is not possible in a more absolute constructivism, where the gradations of truth become either infinitely fine, or barbarically coarse, depending upon your point of view.

Constructive statements can be proven relative to one another, (the same way ZF statements can be proven relative to CH) and if all axioms are carefully traced, we can use the connected facts provisionally when we take their axiomatic bases to be likely in a given circumstance.  (So we can do physics without restricting our use of intervals in bizarre ways.)  But ultimately, statements not grounded absolutely in finite procedures limited by definite rules are simply meaningless mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

Brouwer's intuitionism is very different from other constructivist philosophies. Brouwer's constructions are *mental* (cognitive) constructions rather than pencil and paper constructions.  This enables Brouwer's intuitionism to include countably enumerable sets, while other constructivist approaches may not.

The number π has many *closed-form* (finite) expressions using "infinite" series, so there are many known sequences (of partial sums) that converge to π.  These types of expressions are valid in some constructivist philosophies, but since there are only countably many such expressions, only countably many real numbers may be thus expressed.

Brouwer's intuitionism offers something much stronger than this type of expression - something Brouwer calls a choice sequence.  A choice sequence can converge to **any** real number, not just those that are *computable*.  Unfortunately, we may not know what a given choice sequence converges to since we can only ever inspect finitely many digits.

In Brouwer's philosophy, a statement is true if and only if there exists a proof of that statement.  Thus, with our statement **A** (there exists a sequence of 314159 zero's in the decimal expansion of π), we do not **currently** know if **A** is true or if **not(A)** is true since we currently have no proof.  (This situation gives rise to an example of an instance of the law of the excluded middle that an intuitionist cannot say is true.)

If an intuitionist could prove that π is a [normal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) then the statement **A** would be judged to be true.  Choice sequences offer no solution to this problem since an intuitionist can only inspect finitely many term of a sequence.

It is not clear that a *modal* approach could add anything here in as much as any consistent philosophy that accepts the possibility of future proof of such a statement would appear to accept the possibility that the truth of **A** or **not(A)** could be established in the future.

Comment: I think it is unfair to both Brouwer and Kolmogorov to identify intuitionism as a version of constructivism.  Constructivism is a variety of formalism -- arguments are mathematical if they meet *formal* rules for allowed constructions.  This eliminates one of Brouwer's main dissatisfactions with formalism: that large parts of mathematics are languageless by nature.  What is a construction without language to walk you through the steps?

Comment: @jobermark I agree, although Brouwer's philosophy certain has constructivist elements.  I was attempting to phrase my answer in the context of the question.  I've only just started reading about intuitionalism in the last couple of weeks in prep for an introductory class in phil of maths in the autumn.  Brouwer's dissatisfaction with formalism was total and as far as I understand - formalism and intuitionism are diametrically opposed to one another.  For Brouwer, math came before either language or logic - it determines the logic.

Comment: Yeah, Brouwer even disapproved of Heyting's (pretty completely successful) attempts to make peace between the two as 'that sterile endeavor'.  And, given Heyting's success, everyone gets tied up in the formalism of intuitionism and chucks it into the category of constructivism because that is what it is **formally**.  So he kind of had a point.  Everyone just ignores the underlying philosophy (partly because Brouwer was not a very good proponent of himself.)

Comment: @jobermark That kind of makes me smile - that Heyting should have attempted the role of peace maker.  Coincidentally, I'm just now reading Heyting's paper "The intuitionist foundations of mathematics" where he gives a very interesting analysis of how an intuitionist might (or might not) handle a Dedekind cut.  Well, I found it interesting anyway.  Maybe not for everyone's tastes.